# Add custom field PrestaShop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to add a custom field (HTML textbox) to the admin section in product page. I am following some of the answers in this forum and from Google.

This is my code in `override/classes/Product.php` class:

```
class Product extends ProductCore{

public $product_modal;

function __construct( $id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null ) {

    Product::$definition['fields']['product_modal'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isString');
    parent::__construct( $id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop, $context );
}
```

This is in the `informations.tpl` file:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-3" for="product_modal">
        <span class="label-tooltip" data-toggle="tooltip"
              title="{l s='Product modal'}">
            {$bullet_common_field} {l s='Product modal'}
        </span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" id="product_modal" name="product_modal" value="{$product->product_modal|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I see the new field in product admin page, but when I try to save I am getting this error:

> An error occurred while updating an object. product ()

How can I add a new field in Product page and is there standard PrestaShop way to make that field like description field textbox or I need to third-party jQuery plugin, for the example ?

Comment: Have you added the custom field also in the database?

Comment: Hi, Yes I have added column in a table `ps_product`

Comment: I think there is a problem with the languages for this field and there must be something to do when you add custom field with languages. Because, I have made another without languages and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lang fields are not related with the table `ps_product`, lang fields are related to the table `ps_product_lang`, that's your problem.

Comment: Ok, I need to add columns for all custom fields like `custom_field_LANG_KEY` in the table `ps_product_lang` ?

Comment: * It must add `custom_field_name` column to the table `ps_product_lang` with language key.

Comment: According to your code, in the table `ps_product_lang` you need add a column named `product_modal `.